# How to read first four characters of file name?

Tags: scripts

I have several files whose extensions are .gz with similar filenames to:

```
ANKR00TUR_R_20183350000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
```

I need to read the first four characters of these files' names and store these characters in a file. How can I do this?

Comment: The first 4 bytes of the compressed file or of the uncompressed file?

Comment: compressed file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the code to take first four character of filenames;

```
filename=ANKR00TUR_R_20183350000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
tmp=${filename:0:4}
echo $tmp
```

Result:

```
echo "$tmp"

ANKR
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534301/storing-the-first-4-characters-of-a-filename-into-a-variable)

For a list

```
    for file in ./*.gz
    do
       echo "${file:2:4}" | tee -a list.txt
    done
```

previous for cycle will print on the screen the result and also append to list.txt

Source from [Documentation on The Linux Documentation Project (TLDP)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

**Update**
Improvement of code based on @steeldriver suggestion in comment.

Comment: How can I define 'filename' for all the files (apprx 300) and apply the above code?

Comment: they are all in a directory?

Comment: yes they are all in a directory.

Comment: Don't use `$(ls *.gz)` - see [Bash Pitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver, I'm always get enough lucky and never encountered problems describe in the link you provide. I have improved the answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the first N bytes of a string, `cut` can be used:

```
echo ANKR00TUR_R_20183350000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz | cut --bytes=1-4 > output
```

This will extract the first 4 bytes from the given string and store it in the file `output`.

To apply the above code to multiple filenames, use

```
ls *.gz | cut --bytes=1-4 > output
```

Comment: I applied the command but it produced compressed output file and it cannot be extracted.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you asked for in your question: The first four bytes of the compressed file. Or do you mean the first four bytes of the _filename_ (i.e. ANKR) which is a different case?

Comment: yes, i meant the first four bytes of the filename (i.e. ANKR)

Comment: @deepblue_86 I updated my answer. Now it fetches the first 4 bytes of the _filename_ instead of the _file content_.

Comment: @deepblue_86 Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. [Edit] your post instead and clarify what you actually need.